# How to restore MAC address in Linux?

Tags: linux, mac-address, ifconfig, spoofing

I have changed my MAC address in my Linux machine using `ifconfig`. Now the problem is I have not saved my original MAC address. I want to restore it without rebooting.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Any reason no to reboot?

Comment: Running half a dozen applications. Dont want to close them.

Comment: Run this?: `sudo ifdown interface && sudo ifup interface` Or maybe: `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

Comment: @emb : did not work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get your vendor-specified hardware MAC address using `ethtool`:

```
ethtool -P eth0
```

To reset the MAC address to this value, you can do something like:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether $(ethtool -P eth0 | awk '{print $3}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming eth1:

```
grep "eth1" /var/log/*log | egrep "([0-9a-fA-F]{2}:){5}"
```

could find something in the logs {daemon,kern,syslog}.log on my system.

Answer (score 2):

[rooted] assuming wlan0

...(to find driver)
 `airmon-ng | awk '/wlan0/ {print $4}'` ...or

`airmon-ng | awk '/wlan0/ {print $3}'` ...or just

`airmon-ng` ..and look under 'driver'

...(to restart driver)
`ifconfig wlan0 down`

`modprobe -r rt2800usb`  <=Replace (rt2800usb) with your driver

`modprobe rt2800usb` <=Replace (rt2800usb) with your driver

`ifconfig wlan0 up`

This is how I do it. I made a script for this and use it with a couple of my programs. If that's the route you take, put a 'time.sleep(3)' {or whatever sleep command} before bringing the interface back up.

Answer (score 2):

2021.05.25

The easiest is to use macchanger utility. It is available for every GNU/Linux
distribution.

STEP 1: Disable the network interface you want to restore. Let's say eth0

```
# ip link set eth0 up
```

STEP 2: Restore MAC address using macchanger

```
# macchanger -p eth0
```

STEP 3: Enable the interface

```
# ip link set eth0 up
```

This is it!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try removing then installing the module again?

```
sudo rmmod <NICmodule>
sudo insmod <NICmodule>
```

Or maybe dropping the interface and bringing it back up?

```
sudo ifdown <interface> && sudo ifup <interface>
```

Comment: can you elaborate the first method. The second one did not work.

Comment: The `<NICmodule>` would be what ever kernel module the NIC is using. e.g. e1000 You can see what you have with [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Loadable_Modules).

Comment: Do you know what module your network card uses? This will just remove the module and then put it back (hopefully with the right MAC)

Comment: @narayanpatra Did you replace **interface** with what you use to access the internet? In most cases it's `eth0`

Comment: @thiago : Ya, i did that.